# How to convert list to dictionary

Tags: python

- i have dict below
- Now id is my key
- I need to pack the values
- is there any way to **val like tuple unpacking

```
a = [{ 'id': '123', 'name': 'A', 'type': 'software' },
     { 'id': '102', 'name': 'Adfds', 'type': 'software' },
     { 'id': '222', 'name': 'sxds', 'type': 'software' }]
```

Code is below

```
{{key:val} for each in a for key,val in each.items()}
```

- My out is whole are dictionary which is not correct

Expected out

```
{ '123': { 'name': 'A', 'type': 'software' },
  '102': { 'name': 'Adfds', 'type': 'software' },
  '222': { 'name': 'sxds', 'type': 'software' } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```py
a=[{ 'id': '123', 'name': 'A', 'type': 'software' }, { 'id': '102', 'name': 'Adfds', 'type': 'software' }, { 'id': '222', 'name': 'sxds', 'type': 'software' }]

b = {}

for item in a:
    b[item.pop("id")] = item

b
```

output:

[image]

Comment: how this works, if we pop the id, then it will remove, then how this work?

Comment: @sim, test it, this works, if you pop, you remove id from`dict` that you want

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary cannot have duplicated keys.

In your example you are adding different values to same key. Here what you had to do:

```
res = {each["id"]: {"name": each["name"], "type": each["type"]} for each in a}
```

Comment: "In your example you are adding different values to same key" - Where do you see that?

Comment: is there any way to unpacking like  `res = {each["id"]: **each} for each in a}`
 something like this?

Comment: "Where do you see that?" -> with this (`key,val in each.items()`) line you're adding keys with names `id`, `name` and `type` and with this (`for each in a`) line you are overwriting it.

Comment: @sim since you have want to use `id` value of each dictionary as a key, I can't see a better (or pythonic) way to do it.

Comment: Nah, I'm not doing that, and the OP isn't, either, as that code doesn't even work (dicts aren't hashable) so we can't really say it does anything.

Comment: @sim Try the comp version of user1740577's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```py
{e['id']: dict(i for i in e.items() if i[0] != 'id') for e in a}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and lambda to achieve your goal. Just do:

```
result = dict(map(lambda entry: [entry.pop('id'), entry], a))
print(result)
```

And it gives:

```
{'123': {'name': 'A', 'type': 'software'}, '102': {'name': 'Adfds', 'type': 'software'}, '222': {'name': 'sxds', 'type': 'software'}}
```